# How to join Year and week column with week dates column

Tags: sql-server, date, join, left-join

I have these two columns on separate tables:

A column on table 1, which shows the year and the week. There are duplicates as there are different sets of data belonging to each row in this column on the right side of the table, but I have left this out to make the problem clearer:

```
|.Year Week.|
|..2015 52..|
|..2015 52..|
|..2015 53..|
|..2016 01..|
|....etc....|
|....etc....|
|..2017 23..|
|..2017 23..|
|..2017 23..|
|..2017 24..|
|..2017 25..|
|..2017 25..|
```

Then there's this column on table 2, which shows chronologically the length of a week as you go down the years in 1-week increments. This is more like a calendar table/database:

```
|----Week-----|
|080115_140115|
|150115_210115|
|220115_280115|
|.....etc.....|
|.....etc.....|
|090217_150217|
|160217_220217|
|230217_010317|
```

My question is how do I most efficiently join the weekly column in table 2 with the year week column in table 1 without hard coding any join statements

```
 where [year week] = 'yyyy ww'
```

etc etc?

I was thinking a joint statement at first but realised I have no common column in both tables.

I have to keep the formats for both tables the same. Was thinking, is there away to extract the weeks from the |year week| column into a separate column then join it that way?

I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: While I appreciate that it's a balancing act, I don't think leaving that out makes it clearer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Storing dates in non-date data types often leads to these kinds of problems.  One approach would be to create a mapping table.   This would translate one format into the other.  You could join both your tables to the new table and therefore each other.

Comment: MySql or SQL Server? both are two different databases

Comment: It is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this might not be the most efficient answer, but i did a select distinct statement for table 1 then joined table 2 through excel.

Since this is a static/historical table (and i only need to do it once) i imported the template/data from excel into sql again and used year week as the common column to join the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the year , week from table 1 using string functions and join with the table 2 year and week. Extract year and week from table 2 as shown below.

year is

```
select  DATEPART( year,CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING('080115_140115',0,7),5,2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING('080115_140115',0,7),3,2) +SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING('080115_140115',0,7),0,3),102))
```

week is

```
select  DATEPART( wk,CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING('080115_140115',0,7),5,2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING('080115_140115',0,7),3,2) +SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING('080115_140115',0,7),0,3),102))
```